# Python Pandas Datetime filtering rows before N business day of each month

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime

I would like to filter my dataframe so that it only includes the result between first and 4th business day of each month (including 1st and 4th business days and possible weekend/national holiday days in between). The month or year do not matter. Same date can appear multiple times as long as it is before N:th businessday.

```
             date    score1    
     0   1.7.2020      10      
     1   2.7.2020      15      
     2   2.7.2020      16      
     3   3.7.2020       8  
     4   4.7.2020       2       
     5   5.7.2020       6         
     6   2.8.2020       9       
     7   3.8.2020       5       
     8   3.8.2020       1       
     9   4.8.2020       3       
     10  8.8.2020       0
```

The result should be:

```
             date    score1    
     0   1.7.2020      10      
     1   2.7.2020      15      
     2   2.7.2020      16      
     3   3.7.2020       8  
     4   4.7.2020       2       
     5   5.7.2020       6                   
     7   3.8.2020       5       
     8   3.8.2020       1       
     9   4.8.2020       3
```

Comment: you need to use the `dt.weekday()` and `dt.month()` functions and from there you could select the first 4 business days for every month.

Comment: did the solution work for you?

Comment: So I am only looking for the first 4 businessdays of each month

Comment: I think I see your point. Some business dates can appear twice or more times (for ex. 2.7.2020) but they should one be counted once. To count 4 business days instead of 4 rows (head), I have adapted the code below.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this. Actually, I am looking for something simpler, regardless of the year and month, how can I filter my df to contain only data from the first 4 business days of the month. Therefore there can be multiple times 2.7.2020, but Friday 3.7.2020 and Monday 6.7.2020 results should also be displayed. In this case weekend values could be included as they are before the 4th business days. So from each month I want to see data only before < 5th business day.

Comment: There was an error with the date formatting, interchanging days and months. I now changed this line `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d.%m.%Y')`. Could you check it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the modules:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io
import datetime
```

Read the data:

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""
             date    score1    
     0   1.7.2020      10      
     1   2.7.2020      15      
     2   2.7.2020      16      
     3   3.7.2020       8      
     4   4.7.2020       2       
     5   5.7.2020       6      
     6   2.8.2020       9       
     7   3.8.2020       5       
     8   3.8.2020       1       
     9   4.8.2020       3       
    10  8.8.2020       0    
    """), sep="\s\s+", engine="python")
```

Date formatting:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d.%m.%Y')     
df['weekday'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: x.weekday())
df['day_of_week'] = df['date'].dt.day_name()
df['month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date']).month
df['day_of_month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date']).day
```

Select only first 4 business days of month. As this may (for some months) include weekends of 2 days, each month is minimally counting 4 and maximally 6 days. For example, if Aug 1 is a Saturday, Aug 2 is a Sunday, and four business days is Aug 3 (Mon), Aug 4 (Tue), Aug 5 (Wed) and Aug 6 (Thu), we need to account for 6 days in `day_of_month`.

```
ndf = df[(df['day_of_month'] > 0) & (df['day_of_month'] <= 6)].reset_index(drop=False)
```

The column `day_of_week` is redundant, but I added it to show that Monday is weekday=0, Tuesday is weekday=1 etc. We now know how to select business days (I assume that Saturdays and Sundays are no business days ;-)

```
ndf = ndf[(ndf['weekday'] >= 0) & (ndf['weekday'] < 5)]
```

Only the first 4 business days per month should be displayed.
This is tricky, since one business day can appear in multiple rows.
For ex. 2.7.2020 appeared twice. Therefore, to include 4 business days, the number of *unique* business days should be counted using an index that moves up with every new business day. This is what is done in the following, where `ind1` is an index that only counts with every new business day:

```
ndf['ind1'] = list(ndf.groupby('week')['day_of_week'].transform(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0]))
```

Using `ind1`, we can select rows with 0, 1, 2, or 3 and sort the values by month:

```
ndf[(ndf['ind1'] >= 0) & (ndf['ind1'] < 4)].sort_values(by='month', ascending=True)
```

Comment: How would this work for example in July 2020, where the first 4 business days of the month would be wed : 1st , thu: 2nd, fri:3rd, monday(6th) 4th.

Comment: Thank you Righart for quick responses and help, this has already been helpful!

Comment: ndf['ind1'] = list(ndf.groupby('week')...  you probably mean ndf['ind1'] = list(ndf.groupby('month')

Comment: "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instea"

Comment: But this does the thing and it seems to work! Thank you so much for helping into this! Feels good when it works :)!

Comment: It's a pleasure!

Comment: I encountered problem, if there are few entries, it will show days which are not within 4 first business days of that month. For example if dataset only had entries 6.2, 6.10 and 6.15, it would show these all as they are within first four ind1.. @Righart

Comment: I added another filter to account for that, using the column `day_of_month`. I think the last step `ndf[(ndf['ind1'] >= 0) & (ndf['ind1'] < 4)].sort_values(by='month', ascending=True)` has become redundant now, but you can check if you see any change adding / removing it. Good luck!

Comment: The issue still is that if I have data only consisting of 02 june 2020 and 05 of June 2020, it will show both values even though 5th of June is out of range, it is the fifth business day whereas I only wanted to have entries within first 4 businessdays. Also I think you mean ndf.groupby('month') instead of ndf.groupby('week'). Thank you again for looking into this :)

Answer (score 0):

I came along a more universal and maybe more flexible solution with built in functionalities in pandas.

**Imports**

```
import io
import pandas as pd
```

**Data**

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""
         date    score1    
 0   1.7.2020      10      
 1   2.7.2020      15      
 2   2.7.2020      16      
 3   3.7.2020       8      
 4   4.7.2020       2       
 5   5.7.2020       6      
 6   2.8.2020       9       
 7   3.8.2020       5       
 8   3.8.2020       1       
 9   4.8.2020       3       
10  8.8.2020       0    
"""), sep="\s\s+", engine="python")
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d.%m.%Y')
```

**Code**

```
n_working_days = 4   # Up to how many business days to keep?

df[(df.date >= df.date + pd.offsets.Day() - pd.offsets.MonthBegin()) &
   (df.date < df.date + pd.offsets.Day() - pd.offsets.MonthBegin()+ pd.offsets.BDay(n_working_days))]
```

The code opens a dynamic 'range' to filter on based on the `date` value it is applied to. First, finding the beginning of the month - no magic in that. In the second part the Nth business day timedelta is added by the `BDay` offset to the begin of the month what actually closes the 'range' of acceptable values.

In my personal application i also wanted to have the weekends days filtered out what can be refelcted by adding another filter condition:

```
df[(df.date >= df.date + pd.offsets.Day() - pd.offsets.MonthBegin()) &
   (df.date < df.date + pd.offsets.Day()  - pd.offsets.MonthBegin() + pd.offsets.BDay(n_working_days)) &
   (df.date.dt.dayofweek < 5) # drop saturday and sunday
  ]
```